# Why is my HTML page reloading every time a new entry is submitted into a form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, reload

I am having trouble with my **HTML** page. My program is meant to collect names using a form, then output them into a table below the form. It is capable of doing just that when the page doesn't reload.

The first time I enter a certain name, the page reloads. After the page has reloaded, and I enter the same name, it doesn't reload upon hitting enter any subsequent time. I don't know why this is, or how to fix it.

Here is the linked JS file

```js
// Gloabal Variables
var enteredName,
  countOutput,
  count,
  table,
  form,
  allNames = [];

function project62Part2() {
  // Your code goes in here.
  function getElements() {
    form = document.getElementById("nameForm");
    countOutput = document.getElementById("numNames");
    table = document.getElementById("table");
  }

  function addName() {
    enteredName = form.name.value;
    allNames.push(enteredName);
  }

  function countNames() {
    // Reset count
    count = 0;

    // Loop through and count names
    for (i = 0; i < allNames.length; i++) {
      count++;
    }
  }

  function output() {
    // Reset table
    table.innerHTML = "<tr><th>Names</th></tr>";
    // Display count
    countOutput.innerHTML = "Total names entered: " + count;

    // Loop through and add to table display
    for (i = 0; i < allNames.length; i++) {
      table.innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + allNames[i] + "</td></tr>";
    }
  }

  // Call code
  getElements();
  addName();
  countNames();
  output();

  // Prevent page from reloading
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form id="nameForm" action="#">
  <label class="formLabel" for="name">Name: </label>
  <input id="name" name="name" />

  <input type="submit" name="runExample" value="Submit" class="formatSubmit" onclick="project62Part2()" />
</form>

<div id="numNames">Total names entered: </div>

<table id="table"></table>
```

My understanding of coding is rudimentary at best, so while I would appreciate any answer, I'd prefer it to be kept simple!

Comment: Just use JavaScript by itself: `formElement.onsubmit = project62Part2;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<input type='submit'>` causes the page refresh. Replace it with `<input type='button'>`.

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/submit).

```js
        // Gloabal Variables
    var enteredName,
     countOutput,
     count,
        table,
     form,
     allNames = [];
    
    function project62Part2() {
        // Your code goes in here.
        function getElements() {
      form = document.getElementById("nameForm");
      countOutput = document.getElementById("numNames");
      table = document.getElementById("table");
     }
        
     function addName() {
      enteredName = form.name.value;
      allNames.push(enteredName);
     }
     
     function countNames() {
      // Reset count
      count = 0;
      
      // Loop through and count names
      for (i = 0; i < allNames.length; i++) {
       count++;
      }
     }
     
     function output() {
      // Reset table
      table.innerHTML = "<tr><th>Names</th></tr>";
      // Display count
      countOutput.innerHTML = "Total names entered: " + count;
      
      // Loop through and add to table display
      for (i = 0; i < allNames.length; i++) {
       table.innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + allNames[i] + "</td></tr>";
      }
     }
     
     // Call code
     getElements();
     addName();
     countNames();
     output();
    
     // Prevent page from reloading
     return false;
    }
```

```html
    <form id="nameForm" action="6.2projectpart2.html#">
        <label class="formLabel" for="name">Name: </label>
        <input id="name" name="name" />
        
        <input type="button" name="runExample" value="Submit" class="formatSubmit" onclick="project62Part2()" />
    </form>
    
    <div id="numNames">Total names entered: </div>
    
    <table id="table"></table>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve this I will explain two ways:

#### 1. Adding `Event.preventDefault()` method

Whenever you click `<input>` elements of the `submit` type, the user agent attempts to submit the form to the URL setup in the form.

Now, the `preventDefault()` method tells the user agent that if the event does not get explicitly handled, its default action should not be taken as it normally would be. This means the `Form` interface will not reload the page.

How it works?

- well, just add the event variable to your `submit` call like this:

```html
<input type="submit" name="runExample" value="Submit" class="formatSubmit" onclick="project62Part2(event)" />
```

- Then add the `event` parameter to the `project62Part2()` method.

```js
function project62Part2(event) {
   event.preventDefault();

   ...

}
```

```js
// Gloabal Variables
var enteredName,
  countOutput,
  count,
  table,
  form,
  allNames = [];

function project62Part2(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
  // Your code goes in here.
  function getElements() {
    form = document.getElementById("nameForm");
    countOutput = document.getElementById("numNames");
    table = document.getElementById("table");
  }

  function addName() {
    enteredName = form.name.value;
    allNames.push(enteredName);
  }

  function countNames() {
    // Reset count
    count = 0;

    // Loop through and count names
    for (i = 0; i < allNames.length; i++) {
      count++;
    }
  }

  function output() {
    // Reset table
    table.innerHTML = "<tr><th>Names</th></tr>";
    // Display count
    countOutput.innerHTML = "Total names entered: " + count;

    // Loop through and add to table display
    for (i = 0; i < allNames.length; i++) {
      table.innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + allNames[i] + "</td></tr>";
    }
  }

  // Call code
  getElements();
  addName();
  countNames();
  output();

  // Prevent page from reloading
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form id="nameForm" action="#">
  <label class="formLabel" for="name">Name: </label>
  <input id="name" name="name" />

  <input type="submit" name="runExample" value="Submit" class="formatSubmit" onclick="project62Part2(event)" />
</form>

<div id="numNames">Total names entered: </div>

<table id="table"></table>
```

#### 2. Replacing `input` with `button`

This is based on the previous explanation. If an `<input>` element  of the `submit` type triggers a submit call then if you replace it with the `button` type then a submit call will not be triggered. I recommend you this to maintain the `submit` if you are working with server calls.

How it works?

- well, just replace the type from `submit` to `button` like this:

```html
<input type="button" name="runExample" value="Submit" class="formatSubmit" onclick="project62Part2()" />
```

```js
// Gloabal Variables
var enteredName,
  countOutput,
  count,
  table,
  form,
  allNames = [];

function project62Part2() {
  event.preventDefault();
  // Your code goes in here.
  function getElements() {
    form = document.getElementById("nameForm");
    countOutput = document.getElementById("numNames");
    table = document.getElementById("table");
  }

  function addName() {
    enteredName = form.name.value;
    allNames.push(enteredName);
  }

  function countNames() {
    // Reset count
    count = 0;

    // Loop through and count names
    for (i = 0; i < allNames.length; i++) {
      count++;
    }
  }

  function output() {
    // Reset table
    table.innerHTML = "<tr><th>Names</th></tr>";
    // Display count
    countOutput.innerHTML = "Total names entered: " + count;

    // Loop through and add to table display
    for (i = 0; i < allNames.length; i++) {
      table.innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + allNames[i] + "</td></tr>";
    }
  }

  // Call code
  getElements();
  addName();
  countNames();
  output();

  // Prevent page from reloading
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form id="nameForm" action="#">
  <label class="formLabel" for="name">Name: </label>
  <input id="name" name="name" />

  <input type="button" name="runExample" value="Submit" class="formatSubmit" onclick="project62Part2()" />
</form>

<div id="numNames">Total names entered: </div>

<table id="table"></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding an event parameter on project62Part2 then do an event.preventDefault() inside

Answer (score 0):

You can change from `<input type="submit" name="runExample" />` to

```
<input type="button" name="runExample" />
```

or

Remove `onclick="project62Part2()"` on input tag and move to form tag `onsubmit="return project62Part2()"`

```
<form id="nameForm" onsubmit="return project62Part2()">
```